# How do I prevent iTunes opening in a new virtual screen instead of the current one

Tags: itunes

iTunes used to just open on the screen like other apps, but now it always opens in a new virtual screen taking up the whole screen. This is incredibly annoying how can I get back to the older behaviour ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iTunes is open, move your mouse pointer to the very top of the screen so that the top menu bar drops down. You will then also see the three buttons in the top left corner, but only the green one will be active. Click that and iTunes should pop out of full screen mode.

[image]

Comment: @PaulTaylor Does it open like that even if you've exited full screen mode before closing it?

Comment: Ah, sorry youve fixed it thx

Comment: @PaulTaylor No probs, glad it helped!